# Matplotlib unable to save the file correctly or completely

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

[image]I have been trying to construct visualizations of machine data and I am using pandas dataframe to store the data. I am using a for loop to go select the various slices of the dataset. The visualizations I have constructed has time on the X-axis and because the visualization is in milliseconds the width of the plots is very long.

```
def jobwise_plotter(prog_no):
    df = single_df[single_df['PRG_NO']==prog_no]

    #fig1 = plt.figure()

    #jobs_list = list(df['Job_no'].unique())
    #tools_list = list(df['TOOL_No.'].unique())

    for job in list(df['Job_no'].unique()):

        df_temp = df[df['Job_no']==job]

        time_axis_max = 0

        for tool in list(df_temp['TOOL_No.'].unique()):

            plt.plot(df_temp['Time'][df_temp['TOOL_No.']==tool], 
                     df_temp['Spindle'][df_temp['TOOL_No.']==tool], label=str(tool))



            if int(df_temp['Time'][df_temp['TOOL_No.']==tool].max()) > time_axis_max:
                time_axis_max = int(df_temp['Time'][df_temp['TOOL_No.']==tool].max())




        plt.title("Prog No. : "+ str(prog_no) + ", Job no : "+ str(job) + ", All Tools")

        plt.xlabel("Time (in ms.)")
        plt.ylabel("Spindle Load")

        name = "prog_"+str(prog_no)+"_"+"JOB_"+str(job)+"_All_tools"
        plt.xticks(np.arange(0, time_axis_max+10000, 5000))
        plt.grid(linewidth = 2, linestyle = '-', color='#eff3f9')


        lgd = plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.98), ncol=10)

        plt.tight_layout()
        fig1 = plt.gcf()

        fig1.set_size_inches(100, 10)
        #fig1 = plt.gcf()
        print(name)
        fig1.savefig(name, dpi=500, bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,))

        plt.show()
```

The code is working fine and constructing the necessary visualizations in the IPython notebook but the saved image cannot be viewed (Frozen my system thrice now). 
Is there any limit to image that could be stored? The figure is viewable within the notebook and we can even download it from the browser.

Comment: If you show the intended and actual results would be better. Also, a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be much better as this cannot be replicated.

Comment: I have added the intended image. The image generated by the code cannot be viewed.

Answer (score 2):

The figure shown inside the Jupyter notebook is saved using `fig.savefig(<some buffer>, bbox_inches="tight")`.

Hence, in order to obtain the same figure when saving to disc, you would also need to save it using the `bbox_inches="tight"` argument,

```
fig.savefig("output.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

Comment: Good point. I Changed that in the executed code but I still cannot view the saved image.

Comment: You mean the image is saved, but you cannot open it? You of course need to specify the format to save it in, `fig.savefig("output.png", bbox_inches="tight")` or `fig.savefig("output.whatever", format="png", bbox_inches="tight")`

Comment: In windows and in Linux systems, the filesystem preview shows that its an image but when I click on it, it freezes the system like the viewer is not able to unpack it.

Comment: For the file format, I think even when the format is not mentioned, image is published as a png format. This is not the only part of the code I am using to publish images. The rest of it worked smoothly and could be saved to a file which opens fine. I am suspicious the dimensions of the image may have to do something with it. Please check the image I included in the edit.

Comment: Well, I can well imagine that some image viewers are not capable of displaying a 50000 x 5000 pixel image. (Such an image would probably take >500 MB memory).